# Problemas al hacer una consulta al momento de Agrupar

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero un reporte asi amigos:

```
id  descrip codigo nro idingreso bien     bueno    regular   malo 
01  aceite    2345   2    23      a         3         4        1
02  azucar    2345   4    34      b         2         5        2
```

estoy probando algo así pero no me sale bien me sale puro malo o bien me sale puro bueno porfa ayudenme y si agrego un registro nuevo si ya estaba en malo se va el registro ahi

```
SELECT 
    count(descripcion) as descr, 
    descripcion,codigo, 
    nro, 
    idingreso, 
    bien, 

    case when estado='BUENO' THEN count(estado) ELSE '' END as EB, 
    case when estado='REGULAR' THEN count(estado) else '' end as ER, 
    case when estado='MALO' THEN count(estado) else '' end AS EM 
FROM detalleinventarioinicial 
GROUP BY descripcion 
ORDER BY nro,idingreso asc,descripcion asc
```

Comment: Indicar el manejador de base de datos que usas [editando tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/115581/edit) podría ser muy útil para una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Y en general, vas a tener que aclarar mejor tu pregunta, porque no explicas lo que estás tratando de hacer. Dices que quieres un reporte con 5 columnas, pero tu select tiene 10...

Comment: Parece que estás gritando.

Answer (score 1):

Si no me equivoco lo que tratas de hacer es esto

```
SELECT 
    descripcion, codigo, nro, idingreso, bien, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN estado='BUENO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EB,
    SUM(CASE WHEN estado='REGULAR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ER,
    SUM(CASE WHEN estado='MALO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EM,
FROM detalleinventarioinicial 
GROUP BY descripcion, codigo, nro, idingreso, bien
ORDER BY nro,idingreso asc,descripcion asc
```

sumar los elementos con `estado='BUENO'`, `'REGULAR'` y `'MALO'` en diferentes columnas.

Comment: lo probare amigo Asier Villanueva gracias por la respuesta

Comment: no nada amigo  Asier Villanueva no me sale nada gracias por tomarte un tiempito....